# SVG in a table not scaling in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, svg

I am trying to make a more or less responsive layout with some images in a table. So I thought I should use SVG for it, now doing that everything works fine except with Internet Explorer: I have a inline SVG in a td-element and it would be nice if the SVG re-sizes according to parent element. No matter what I try I am not able to archive it.
A reduced example is here:

HTML

```
<table id="F">
    <tr>
        <td class="container">
            <svg id="bar-graph" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                        <rect height="100" width="100"></rect>
            </svg>
        </td>
        <td class="container" style="background-color:red;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width:50%;
}
#bar-graph {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
#F {
    width:50px;
}
```

Here is the example in a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/julianrath/v9hpazun/13/

If you open that with Firefox or Chrome and re-size the output window *both* tds are going to take 50%(in the example ~25px) of the table space. In internet explorer the inline-SVG does not re-size at all.

EDIT: Tested with IE9 and IE11.

EDIT: Corrected fiddle link

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=svg

Comment: Using IE9 and IE11, it is rendered, what are you referring to specifically?

Comment: Didn't read the question, just posted that to see if your browser had support since you didn't specify the version of IE as far as I scanned it. All I see in Firefox is a tiny red vertical bar. In Chrome it works. Have you tried the suggestions here: http://soqr.fr/testsvg/embed-svg-liquid-layout-responsive-web-design.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I learned today that `table-layout` is a really important property if you want to scale something in a table depended on the layout of the table and not the other way around (scaling the table layout depending on the content of the table).  Unfortunately Internet Explorer and the others have a different understanding of the [`table-layout:auto`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp) property.

```
#F {
    width:50px;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/julianrath/v9hpazun/26/